# Using a standalone CDF to replace a typical graphing calculator

Tags: graphics, manipulate, cdfplayer

I can use `Manipulate[]` to create a grapher that emulates some of the functionality of a typical graphing calculator.By using `InputField` as a control, the user can type in a function into the field and Mathematica will produce the graph on the fly.

Today I noticed that I can deploy this grapher as a `standalone CDF` and it still works using the `CDF player` alone. Then Mathematica does not need to be running.

I didn't realize this was possible.  I was thinking of creating a grapher and then parking it as a standalone CDF in my dropbox.  This would offer my students a free alternative to purchasing a physical `graphing calculator`, `Mathematica`, etc.

These are some questions in my mind:

- Is this plausible?
- Does a standalone CDF have enough power to be used a standalone functional graphing calculator with multiple controls that emulates buttons on a physical graphing calculator?
- Has anyone seen a decent standalone `CDF grapher`?

I'm curious on whether its worth my time to build one.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Any one can run any CDF, by using the player. But the free player do not allow non-numeric input in the input field. `InputField as a control the user can type in a function into the field` so this will not be possible. You'd need the pro CDF. Here is the chart [how-player-pro-compares](https://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html) Look for the `Keyboard entry to text fields` entry. This requires the EnterpriseCDF version.

Comment: Here is a [PocketCalculator](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PocketCalculator/) at the demo site. One way you can do what you want without text input field, is to use pop-up menu and have pre-selected functions to choose from.

Comment: It could certainly be done but it would be a fairly time-consuming project. If your student's already have a computer that can run CDF Player, why not have them use one of the free graphing calculator apps that already exist? Macs come with one installed -- Grapher.